# how to control selected and unselected background color for the SegmentedButton widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying the new [`SegmentedButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SegmentedButton-class.html) widget:

```dart
SegmentedButton<int>(
  onSelectionChanged: (i) {},
  showSelectedIcon: false,
  style: ButtonStyle(
    backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
    iconColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white),
  ),
  segments: const <ButtonSegment<int>>[
    ButtonSegment<int>(
      value: 12,
      icon: Icon(FlutterRemix.thumb_up_fill),
      enabled: true,
    ),
    ButtonSegment<int>(
      value: 20,
      icon: Icon(FlutterRemix.thumb_down_fill),
    ),
  ],
  selected: {12},
),
```

This code shows the two segmented buttons like this:

[image: SegmentedButton]

How can I customize the color od the selected and unselected buttons, when I set:

```dart
backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
```

It does set the background color for both selected and selected.

Thank you!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can control this with Material States:

```
backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
   (Set<MaterialState> states) {
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)){
        return Colors.green;
      }
      return Colors.red;
    },
 ),
```

Comment: the SegmentedButton widget doesnt have a backgroundColor attribute. Can you edit your answer to be more clear how this is to be applied?

Comment: there is a style property in SegementedButton and you can do `style: ButtonStyle( backgroundColor: ... )`

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, it only works if I remove `backgroundColor` and add other code:

```dart
class SegmentedButtonTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const SegmentedButtonTest({super.key});

  @override
  State<SegmentedButtonTest> createState() => _SegmentedButtonTestState();
}

class _SegmentedButtonTestState extends State<SegmentedButtonTest> {
  int selected = 12;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SegmentedButton<int>(
      onSelectionChanged: (Set<int> i) {
        setState(() {
          selected = i.first;
        });
      },
      showSelectedIcon: false,
      style: ButtonStyle(
        iconColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white),
      ),
      segments: const <ButtonSegment<int>>[
        ButtonSegment<int>(
          value: 12,
          icon: Icon(FlutterRemix.thumb_up_fill),
          enabled: true,
        ),
        ButtonSegment<int>(
          value: 20,
          icon: Icon(FlutterRemix.thumb_down_fill),
        ),
      ],
      selected: {selected},
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You might need to make the button style dynamic, based on the current selected value. Here is a basic example of how this could be achieved:

```
function Category() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.textHeader}>Categories</Text>

      <SegmentedButtons
        value={value}
        onValueChange={setValue}
        buttons={[
          {
            value: 'expenses',
            label: 'Exprenses',
            style: {
              backgroundColor: value === 'expenses' ? 'blue' : 'white',
            },
          },

          {
            value: 'incomes',
            label: 'Incomes',
            style: {
              backgroundColor: value === 'incomes' ? 'blue' : 'white',
            },
          },
        ]}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what "enter code here" means in the context of your answer. Also some of your code is outside of the code block.